# Chromevox reads a video duration 16:02 (16 mn 2s) as "16 hours 2 minutes"

Tags: html, accessibility

In [TED](https://www.ted.com/) website, when using ChromeVox screenreader (with French configuration), the videos duration are read for example "16 heures 2" when it's written "16:02".

But we're actually talking about minutes and seconds, not hours and minutes. What is the correct markup to make this screenreader read the time correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why this post had been put on hold. i edited your question so that it might be clearer. You may use the `time` tag. *Eg.* `<time pubdate="P16M2S">16:02</time>`

Answer (score 2):

ChromeVox detects "16:02" as being a format for an hour. You can use the time tag:

```
Eg. <time pubdate="P16M2S">16:02</time>
```

But there's no certainty that it would be correctly handled by other screenreaders